# Seaborn plots appending legends when plotting multiple plots in the same script

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am new to Seaborn. When plotting multiple plots in the same script, the first plot is correct, but for the rest, the legends are appended which skew the plots.

**My code**

```
sns.set()
cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(rot=-.2, as_cmap=True)
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="Clicks", y="Impressions",
                     hue="Language2", size="CTR",
                     palette=cmap, sizes=(10, 200),
                     data=df)
ax.get_figure().savefig('Test plot.png')

sns.set()
cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(rot=-.2, as_cmap=True)
ax0 = sns.scatterplot(x="Impressions", y="Clicks",
                      hue="Word2", size="Transactions",
                      palette=cmap, sizes=(10, 200),
                      data=df)
ax0.get_figure().savefig('Test plot 2.png')

sns.set()
cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(rot=-.2, as_cmap=True)
ax1 = sns.scatterplot(x="CTR", y="CostPerTransaction",
                      hue="Language2", size="Transactions",
                      palette=cmap, sizes=(10, 200),
                      data=df)
ax1.get_figure().savefig('Test plot 3.png')
```

I am not sure if I should use `sns.set()` each time. I've renamed each ax but the issue persists.

[image: Plot one]

[image: Plot two]

Also, maybe you could suggest how I could improve my plots.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Probably you need to call `plt.clf()` after saving the image so the plot gets cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain if this will fix your problem. But in general I have a strong preference for using the explicit object oriented approach whenever creating more than one plot in matplotlib/seaborn (matplotlib is the underlying library, seaborn is just wrapping it to make certain applications quicker). This means getting rid of the `ax.get_figure().savefig` parts. I found [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-matplotlib-guide/) really useful in understanding the object oriented matplotlib approach compared to the implicit state approach.

Your code in this method would look like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(rot=-.2, as_cmap=True)
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
sns.scatterplot(x="Clicks", y="Impressions",
                     hue="Language2", size="CTR",
                     palette=cmap, sizes=(10, 200),
                     data=df,
                     ax=ax1)
# This may help with your axes labels spilling off the figure:
fig1.tight_layout()
fig1.savefig('Test plot.png')


#  the sns.set is not needed each time
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
# cmap is the same, so we don't need to define that again
sns.scatterplot(x="Impressions", y="Clicks",
                      hue="Word2", size="Transactions",
                      palette=cmap, sizes=(10, 200),
                      data=df,
                      ax=ax2)
fig2.savefig('Test plot 2.png')

fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()
sns.scatterplot(x="CTR", y="CostPerTransaction",
                      hue="Language2", size="Transactions",
                      palette=cmap, sizes=(10, 200),
                      data=df,
                      ax=ax3)
fig3.savefig('Test plot 3.png')
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, sir.